# Javascript on Dropdown Select for Location

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to Javascript and I need help.

I have my registration form with some sort of address / location field. By default the place is PHILIPPINES, so they need to select the regions in the philippines (drop down) then the towns / cities in that particular region they selected.

A region can have many towns / cities.

How can I make it that when they select on a dropdown menu a region then list of cities will appear to another dropdown which belongs to that particular region.

or is there any pre-made javascript out there for that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can listen for the change event in region select box and change the content of cities select box based on the selected value. Also note that this technique is using jQuery.

```
<select id="region"></select>
<select id="cities"></select>

$("#region").on('change', function () {
   $("#cities").html('<option>city1</option><option>city2</option>');
});
```

Comment: Jquery? do i need to download it first? and include it in my scrip src? is compatible with bootstrap? I'm using bootstrap for my ui

Comment: Yes. And it is compatible with bootstrap.

Comment: As I'm looking in the code you gave, I can't see an if-else statement? That code will work?

Comment: You can implement your logic inside the callback function. I just showed you how you can change the content of cities dropdown when the region is changed